# GEt element By id angular 7

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, get, angular7

hello I need to retrieve the values entered by a form after the post method so I inserted at the service level this code :

```
 list:Client[];


 constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
 postClient(formData:Client){

  return this.http.post(this.rootURL+'/Clients/',formData);
 }
 putClient(formData:Client){

   return this.http.put(this.rootURL+'/Clients/'+formData.Engagement,formData);
  }
  getClient(formData:Client){

   return this.http.get(this.rootURL+'/Clients/GetClientByName/'+formData.Engagement);
  }
```

and at the component level like this :

```
 getClient(form:NgForm){

  this.clientservice.getClient(form.value).subscribe(
    res =>{this.client = res as Client}
  )



 }
```

and in the HTML code this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>

                                <th class="tname">Client</th>
                                <th class="tname">Enagement</th>
                                <th class="tname">ERP</th>



                            </tr>
                            <tr *ngFor="let clt of client">

                                <td >{{clt.Clientname}}</td>
                                <td >{{clt.Engagement}}</td>
                                <td >{{clt.ERP}}</td>
```

and I can’t get the values by ID with the get I don’t know  what is the problem I have neither result or error message

Answer (score 1):

I think your http service(this.rootURL+'/Clients/GetClientByName/) return Client[] not Client.
So, You should cast like this.

```js
  this.clientservice.getClient(form.value).subscribe(
    res =>{this.client = res as Client[]}
  )
```

But, your response is fixed

```
 {"Engagement":"56789","Clientname":"ClLIENT","ERP":"ERP"}
```

at component level, no need to edit

```
 getClient(form:NgForm){

  this.clientservice.getClient(form.value).subscribe(
    res =>{this.client = res as Client}
  )



 }
```

you should edit html file.

```html
<table class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>

                                <th class="tname">Client</th>
                                <th class="tname">Enagement</th>
                                <th class="tname">ERP</th>



                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td >{{client.Clientname}}</td>
                                <td >{{client.Engagement}}</td>
                                <td >{{client.ERP}}</td>
                            </tr>
```

### ---------------------------

---

or need to use ngFor loop, edit component level. and no need to edit component level.

```
 client: Client[] = [];
 getClient(form:NgForm){

  this.clientservice.getClient(form.value).subscribe(
    res =>{
            const cli = res as Client;
            this.client.length = 0;
            Array.prototype.push.apply(this.client, cli)
      }
  )



 }
```

Comment: Same thing I tried to add the[] and I have no result

Comment: Can you see service response by Chrome Debugger?
press F12 button and click Network tab in Debugger. And generate request, you can see response by Debugger. confirm your response same as you want.

Comment: I have already tested the API request by POSTMAN and I have the response that i want I think that the problem is at the level of the code insert in angular in order to generate the data by ID

Comment: can you see your expected response?

Comment: My extected response is [{"ClientName":"cli1", "Engagement":"eng1", "ERP":1},{"ClientName":"cli2", "Engagement":"eng2", "ERP":2}]. or [{"ClientName":"cli1", "Engagement":"eng1", "ERP":1}]
If your Expected response is {"ClientName":"cli1", "Engagement":"eng1", "ERP":1}, this can't do ngFor loop. change your response.

Comment: I started this request http://localhost:61191/api/Clients/Getclientbyname/56789
with 56789 IS THE engagement NUMBER and as an answer I have this
{"Engagement":"56789","Clientname":"ClLIENT","ERP":"ERP"}...                                        If I want the granny answered at the angulAr level and I don’t use ngFor loop then I use what??

Comment: If you response is fixed 
 as {"Engagement":"56789","Clientname":"ClLIENT","ERP":"ERP"}, 
at component level, 
```
  this.clientservice.getClient(form.value).subscribe(
    res =>{this.client = res as Client}
  )
```
and, at HTML level
```
<tr>
    <td >{{client.Clientname}}</td>
    <td >{{client.Engagement}}</td>
    <td >{{client.ERP}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I modified the answer as you mark and I have an error in the console :core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Engagement' of undefined
    at ClientprocessitComponent_Template (clientprocessit.component.html:80)

Comment: I think this error occurs  reasons below.
* client is Null object
* client has no property Engagement
each or both I don't know.

Comment: when i add this client: Client= {  Clientname: "",Engagement: "",ERP:"" }; in the component I have more this error and I have no results either

Comment: At  your error, Clientname is valid.so, Engagement has spell miss, in each code, I think.

Comment: comment out L80, run again.

Comment: I don't understand why the recovery of the data from component does not work in say I input new attributes not that which are entered in the method post

Comment: I did your code in stackblitz. no error occur. check this site.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wdyykf)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it